# Не работает клавиатура, после обновления драйверов

Tags: windows-10, клавиатура, драйвер

После неудачного обновление драйверов(выдало ошибку сбой ПО), клавиатура выключилась и не работает вообще(на трех устройствах проверял). В разделе «Устройства и принтеры» показывает, что она теперь wpn usb, что это значит?
Буду благодарен, если предложите свои идеи, по поводу решения этой проблемы.
ОС: Windows 10
клавиатура: dark project kd87a

Comment: Драйвера ставятся в ОС, это же не прошивка. Это не влияет на работу на других устройствах. Похоже, проблема в железе. Сдавайте в сервисный центр.

Comment: у меня сейчас такая же точь в точь проблема как была у тебя. Ты её решил если да то как?